# Apollo server serve static files

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have the following stack: Nodejs, Apollo Server, React+Apollo Client, Postgres.
I have a pretty simple app for the sake of the question lets imagine it's a blog. Users create posts with some text and images. My first setup was express as a middleware that was responsible for uploading images and serving them as static files. But then I learned that I can upload images with Apollo Server and express began to seem kind of pointless. But with this setup (without express) I can't figure out how to serve images afterwards. It seems Apollo Server only can't do it. Or I couldn't find any info.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are using an apollo graphql standalone server or apollo server with express middleware. In both ways, we can not serve static files with express.static() middleware like we used to do in REST Apis.

**So there are two ways to resolve this issue of serving static files -**

**1). Using GraphQl itself with Query to execute resolver where we will pass unique file identifier like name and it will return content say (base64 for images)**

- Create a GraphQL query or mutation that accepts a unique identifier
  or filename for the image.
- In the resolver function for that query or
  mutation, read the file from the disk and return it as the response.
- Make sure to set the appropriate Content-Type header in the response.
- On the client-side, you can use the returned image data to display
  the image.

Example:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getImage: (_, { id }) => {
      // Assuming each image has a unique identifier as its filename
      const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public/images', `${id}.jpg`);

      // Check if the image file exists
      if (fs.existsSync(imagePath)) {
        // Read the image file as binary data
        const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
        const imageData = Buffer.from(imageBuffer).toString('base64');

        // Return the image URL and data
        return {
          id,
          url: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`
        };
      } else {
         throw new GraphQLError('Image not found', {
           extensions: {
            code: 'CLIENT_ERROR',
            http: {
              status: 404,
            },
          },
         });
      }
    },
  },
};
```

**2. Use Nginx to serve static content with defined content of server block as shown below**

```
 # Define this root directive in your server block from where to serve the static files.
 root /opt/nodeapis/demo_project;
 
 # Serving static images by trying all files in the root location which matches the requested URL params like - assets/images/filename.jpeg
 location = /assets {
     try_files $uri =404; 
 }
```

Hope this will help you or somebody else. Thanks!

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score -2):

Ok it seems I found an answer myself. It's possible to serve them with nginx in this setup

Comment: Some more details please?